# Автоматическое обрезание фото при использовании UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, изображения, камера

Доброго дня всем!

В моем проекте реализована выборка фото из библиотеки, ну или с камеры. Грубо говоря позволяю пользователю добавить фото или изображение к аккаунту.

В данный момент размер принимаемого UIImageView 200х200 и при выборе изображения оно не масштабируется под размер UIImageView.

Но скриншоте можно посмотреть что в итоге получается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно правильно реализовать автомасштабирование и обрезание фото.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1):

во первых выставьте

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true;
```

таким образом вы будете получать квадратную фотку на выходе. Ее можно получить так:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    /* Do stuff here */
}
```

дальше берете любое решение (удобнее всего категорию `UIImage`) с этого сайта для пропорционального резайза фотки и все готово!

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!